# Using software (.dll) written in .Net Framework 2.0 for UWP Apps

Tags: c#, .net, dll, uwp, compatibility

I am developing a UWP App and want to use some libraries which are developed in .Net Framework 2.0 ([Subsembly FinTS API](https://subsembly.com/fints-api.html)) 
When I include them into my UWP projekt and try to build the app i get the following errors:

1. Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file
   `System.Windows.Forms.dll`
2. `Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.`

So my qestion ist: Are .Net Framework 2.0 and .Net Core (UWP) compatible? Or is there a way to make them compatible?

Comment: You simply can't. UWP doesn't support System.Windows.Forms, or many of the other parts of "full" .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use full .NET Framework libraries in UWP apps directly.

The only way to make it work is using so-called **Brokered Windows Runtime Components**. This technique works only with **side-loaded apps on desktop** (you can't publish the app on the Windows Store) and requires a proxy component that will allow communication between the Windows Store app and the full CLR server component.

The server class library can reference the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` and the proxy component provides Windows Runtime-safe access to invoke the code inside the server library. That means you can actually show a Windows Forms `MessageBox` from UWP for example.

You can learn more about this [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps) along with the full documentation on how to achieve this.